# Simpson's Rule Question with Example

Tags: integration, approximate-integration, simpsons-rule

I'm just learning Simpson's Rule for integral approximation and I have a question.
$
\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)dx\:approx=\frac{\frac{b-a}{n}}{3}\left[\left(1f\left(x0\right)\right)+4f\left(x1\right)+2f\left(x2\right)...\right]$

I'm trying to use Simpson to approximate the area under 1/x a=1 b=2 with an n=10.

Here is what I have so far:
$\int _1^2\frac{1}{x}dx\:approx=\frac{1}{30}\left[\frac{1}{\frac{1}{10}\cdot 0}+4\frac{1}{\frac{1}{10}\cdot 1}...\right]$

What's tripping me up is the first f(x0). It clearly evaluates to 10/0, which is undefined. Where is my error?

I appreciate any assistance provided!

Comment: How have you defined $x_{n}$?

Comment: I THINK I may have figured out my error. I definied xn as $\frac{1}{n\cdot deltax}$ when in fact it needs the lower bound included. So xn should be definied as $"\frac{1}{a+n\cdot deltax}=\frac{1}{1+n\cdot deltax}=\frac{1}{1+n\cdot \frac{1}{10}}"$. Can someone confirm my intitution here is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error lies, as my comment tries to hint at, in the definition of $x_{i}$.

For Simpson's rule with $n+1$ points we have that
$$x_{i}=a+i\frac{b-a}{n} \tag{$i=0,1,\dots,n$}.$$

This gives us in your case

$$x_{i}=1+i\frac{1}{10} \tag{$i=0,1,\dots,9,10$}$$

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: @findingmyway If your consider the question answered, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer.